# Does the removePopUp method, removes eventListeners too?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

```
public function doAddItem(itemConcepto:int):void{
                modalCfd = new modalCFDItems();
                modalCfd.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, closeHandler);
                modalCfd.addEventListener("addItemResult", addItem_resultHandler);
                modalCfd.addEventListener("addItemResize", addItemResize_resultHandler);                
                PopUpManager.addPopUp(modalCfd, this, true)
                PopUpManager.centerPopUp(modalCfd);
            }
            private function addItem_resultHandler(event:Event):void{   
                addItemStuff();
                PopUpManager.removePopUp(modalCfd);
                removeListeners("modalCfd");
            }
```

Does that do it, or do I have to removeEventListener explicitly?

Comment: Have you tried tracing the value of `modalCfd` after calling removePopUp?  It may be that the reference is lost, so you should remove the listeners before removing the popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to always remove listeners if you want the GC to kick in.
There is just no way around it.
And also NULL the object is best too.

Comment: `asMan` is right. I believe you can also use *weak* references, but I recommend you only use that in **needed** situations.